# cx_freeze & pygobject in a subdirectory

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pygobject

I have a small py program that using py27 & pygtk. I can freeze this this quite happily with cx_freeze.

I have been attempting to "port" it over to py33 & pygobject.  This has been completed quite successfully and I am not trying to adapt my setup.py cx_freeze script to now "freeze" the application.

I am able to freeze a test application but when I then try to use my tweaked version I receive a ImportError. What I have done is I have made all the binary data go into a subdirectory (bin) to try to keep the root a bit less unclutter.

As mentioned this works fine with py27 & pygtk.

I have shrunk it downto a simple py and setup to demonstrate this:

TEST.py

```
########################################################################
import os
import sys

if getattr(sys,'frozen',False):
    # if trap for frozen script wrapping
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin'))
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin\\etc'))
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin\\lib'))
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin\\share'))
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin\\library.zip'))
    os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin\\tcl')
    os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin\\tk')
    os.environ['MATPLOTLIBDATA'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin\\mpl-data')

import gi
import gi.repository 
from gi.repository import Gtk
#######################################################################
```

setup.py

```
########################################################################
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import site
import os

site_dir = site.getsitepackages()[1]
include_dll_path = os.path.join(site_dir, "gnome")

missing_dll = ['libgtk-3-0.dll',
               'libgdk-3-0.dll',
               'libatk-1.0-0.dll',
               'libcairo-gobject-2.dll',
               'libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll',
               'libjpeg-8.dll',
               'libpango-1.0-0.dll',
               'libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll',
               'libpangoft2-1.0-0.dll',
               'libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll',
               'libgnutls-26.dll',
              # 'libgcrypt-11.dll',
               #'libp11-kit-0.dll'
]
gtk_libs = ['etc', 'lib', 'share']   
include_files = []
for dll in missing_dll:
    include_files.append((os.path.join(include_dll_path, dll), dll))     

for lib in gtk_libs:
    include_files.append((os.path.join(include_dll_path, lib), lib))        

includes = ['gi']
excludes = ['wx','email','pydoc_data','curses']
packages = ['gi']
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '.', 'bin'))



EXE1 = Executable(
    script = "test.py",
    initScript = None,
    base = 'Console',
    targetDir = "dist",
    targetName = "test.exe",
    compress = True,
    copyDependentFiles = True,
    appendScriptToExe = True,
    appendScriptToLibrary = False,
    )

setup(

    version = "9999",
    description = "test",
    author = "jrb",
    name = "test",

    options = {"build_exe": {"includes": includes,
                             "excludes": excludes,
                             "packages": packages,
                             'include_files':include_files,
                             "path": sys.path,

                            'append_script_to_exe':False,
                            'build_exe':"dist/bin",
                            'compressed':True,
                            'copy_dependent_files':True,
                            'create_shared_zip':True,
                            'include_in_shared_zip':True,
                            'optimize':2,
                             }
               },

    executables = [EXE1]
    )
########################################################################
```

now when I run: /c/Python33/python -OO setup.py build 
and then execute dist/test.exe I have printed to the console:

ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console3.py", line 27, in 
    exec(code, m.**dict**)
  File "test.py", line 19, in 
ImportError: cannot import name Gtk

I have checked and the typelib files exist but for whatever reason python & gi cannot find them. I thought it might be a missing path to girepository but that didn't fix it. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
os.environ['GI_TYPELIB_PATH'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin\\lib\girepository-1.0')
```